# Maven Java Project: Having errors on my pom.xml trying to use JPA on eclipse

Tags: maven, jpa, eclipselink, pom.xml, persistence.xml

I'm working on a project that will use JPA to persist and retrieve objects from my SQL workbench database.

Whenever i'm trying to utilise the EntityManager from JPA i get an error:

**Error**:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.getInitializer(PersistenceProvider.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:190)
    at java.persistence@2.1-api-1.0.2.Final/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at java.persistence@2.1-api-1.0.2.Final/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at fluvius.gr16@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/repository.GenericDaoJpa.<clinit>(GenericDaoJpa.java:12)
    at fluvius.gr16@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/domain.Fluvius.setDaos(Fluvius.java:31)
    at fluvius.gr16@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/domain.Fluvius.<init>(Fluvius.java:26)
    at fluvius.gr16@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/domain.DomeinController.<init>(DomeinController.java:20)
    at fluvius.gr16@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/main.StartUp.start(StartUp.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 18 more
Exception running application main.StartUp
```

**persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="fluvius" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>domein.User</class>
        <class>domein.Color</class>
        <class>domain.Category</class>
        <class>domein.Sdg</class>
        <class>domein.SubSdg</class>
        <class>domein.GraphData</class>
        <class>domein.Mvo</class>


        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gr16node?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="crazydifficultpassword"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hogent.fluvius.gr16</groupId>
    <artifactId>fluvius.gr16</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!--  JAVAFX BUILD PROPERTY -->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.version>17.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

<!--JPA -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
-->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


<!-- EINDE JPA-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JACKSON MAPPER (word gebruikt voor JSON te mappen naar objecten (bv. GraphData)-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--  JAVA FX 17.0.1 -->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
            <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>StartUp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Module-info**:

```
module fluvius.gr16 {
  requires javafx.fxml;
  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.base;
  requires java.persistence;
  requires javafx.graphics;
  requires java.sql;
  requires de.mkammerer.argon2.nolibs;
  requires com.sun.jna;
  requires org.controlsfx.controls;
  requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
requires commons.csv;

  exports gui;
  exports main;

  // opens main to javafx.fxml
  opens gui.controllers to javafx.fxml;
  opens gui.components to javafx.fxml;
}
```

I've spend probably like 4 hours already looking up existing problems and answers, but none of these are working for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with:     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> inside the persistence.xml? This is the first project i'm doing on maven, so i'm quite unsure where to look.

Comment: Which JDK do you use?

Comment: Looks like a JDB Bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077620

Comment: @Jens  i'm using jdk-17.0.2

Comment: You can try using jdk8 or jdk11